# Using jira key as part of the unit test case name

Tags: unit-testing, junit, tdd, testng, junit4

my project is entering a system test phase. I would like to introduce the practice of every bug leading to code change to be supplemented with relevant Unit Test testing the modification.

I was wondering if it makes sense to add the Jira key of the bug that has spawned the test to the end of the test case name.

Does this makes sense? Is this good practice, or if not why ?

Thanks

Comment: This is likely to be closed as opinion-based, but I've posted my opinion :)

Answer (score 1):

Writing a failing unit test that demonstrates the presence of a bug is a very good idea, but adding a reference to an external tracking system in the test name will likely require a future developer to look up the bug to fully understand the test.  Better to make the test name describe the desired behavior of the system.  For code readability in the long run, it really doesn't matter whether a test was written during initial coding or later phases.  They should all describe the desired behavior of the system.

Answer (score 1):

Unit Test does not test bugs in general, but some part of your functionality (as the other types of testing). As for me, there is now need to track Jira issue (task or bug) as part of test case name. But you can use them like additional information in test report, like Allure Report [do](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-core/wiki/Issues).